# How to pin NetBeans to Windows 8 (x64) taskbar?

Tags: windows, java, taskbar, netbeans, pin

I've googled around and it seems that I'm not the only one with the problem, however I couldn't find the solution. Maybe someone around here has figured it out.

The problem is that netbeans.exe is actually a stub which is calling javaw.exe. When I try to pin the NetBeans process to the taskbar I actually pin "Java(TM) Platform SE Binary". That changes the icon and the pin doesn't work.

The funny thing is that it works on another machine. I don't know whether it's because it's a different version of NetBeans, or a different version of Java.

Has anyone figured this out?

Added: I know this is sort of not programming related; on the other hand there are plenty of topics around here about how to better your programming environment, and this one is no worse than those.

Oh, and btw - Windows 8 x64; Java JDK 1.7; Netbeans 7.1.2

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://www.strixcode.com/sevenbeans/)? Don't know if it works for Windows 8.

Comment: Ohhh 10x criziot :)

Comment: @criziot, looks good, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Hm, I'm missing icons in Jump List, and Tabbed Thumbnails are not working for me...I think I should wait for EightBeans :)

Answer (score 2):

Press F3 (or go to the top right corner and click on the lens), search for Netbeans, right click on it and Pin :)

Answer (score 2):

When using a 64-bit OS, change the NetBeans shortcut to use netbeans64.exe instead of netbeans.exe before you pin it.

You can probably also right-click the pinned icon, right-click the NetBeans shortcut, select Properties, and then change the Target to use netbeans64.exe instead of netbeans.exe.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem, need to use the right executable depending on OS version. Solved for me on Windows 10. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Just open netbeans, click right on the icon and "Pin it"

[image]